# Odd behavior of FindFile

Tags: packages, files-and-directories

Running `FindFile` gives some odd results on my machine:

```
FindFile["HTTPClient`"]
```

Result:

```
/Users/kratky/Library/Mathematica/Paclets/Repository/HTTPClient-10.1.33/Kernel/init.m
```

The path `/Users/kratky/Library/Mathematica/Paclets/Repository` is not on the `$Path`.

```
$Path // TableForm

/Applications/Mathematica 10.1.app/Contents/SystemFiles/Links
/Users/kratky/Library/Mathematica/Kernel
/Users/kratky/Library/Mathematica/Autoload
/Users/kratky/Library/Mathematica/Applications
/Library/Mathematica/Kernel
/Library/Mathematica/Autoload
/Library/Mathematica/Applications
.
/Users/kratky
/Applications/Mathematica 10.1.app/Contents/AddOns/Packages
/Applications/Mathematica 10.1.app/Contents/SystemFiles/Autoload
/Applications/Mathematica 10.1.app/Contents/AddOns/Autoload
/Applications/Mathematica 10.1.app/Contents/AddOns/Applications
/Applications/Mathematica 10.1.app/Contents/AddOns/ExtraPackages
/Applications/Mathematica 10.1.app/Contents/SystemFiles/Kernel/Packages
/Applications/Mathematica 10.1.app/Contents/Documentation/English/System
/Applications/Mathematica 10.1.app/Contents/SystemFiles/Data/ICC
```

How does Mathematica's paclet manager interfere with the package search path? This does not seem to be documented properly anywhere.

Comment: Possibly related? [(59127)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/59127/121)

Comment: I'm not sure about the details of PacletManager, but note that the file you mentioned is located inside `$UserBasePacletsDirectory`.