# Why does leaving and re-entering a context lose values defined in that context?

Tags: symbols, contexts

I'm getting unexpected behavior when beginning a new context, leaving it, and then re-entering it. Specifically, when re-entering the context, symbols that had been previously defined in that context now seem to have lost their values... but I can recapture them by explicitly supplying the context. Consider this example:

```
Begin["sandbox`"];
a = 1;
ValueQ[a]
End[];

(* ==> True *)

ValueQ[a]

(* ==> False *)

Begin["sandbox`"];
Names[Evaluate[Context[]] <> "*"]
ValueQ[a]
ValueQ[sandbox`a]
End[];

(* ==> {"sandbox`a"} *)
(* ==> False *)
(* ==> True *)
```

NB: Quit the *Mathematica* kernel before evaluating this example, every time. Re-evaluating the whole thing subsequent times changes the results, so that **all** of the ValueQ tests now return True. (I also have absolutly no idea why that happens.)

My questions are: Why doesn't switching back into the "sandbox`" context give me un-prefixed access to symbols in that context, and is there any way to work around this that doesn't require explicitly providing the context? (In my real application, always specifying the context once it has been left and re-entered isn't practical.)

FYI, the reason I'm investigating this is that I'm trying to set up a kind of clean-ish "sandbox" context where some unknown code can be evaluated, and then test code I've written can inspect the definitions/values/etc. that it leaves behind. Because of the way the application is factored, its hard to avoid leaving and re-entering the sandbox context.

Comment: Related: [(8295)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8295/121), [(43381)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/43381/121)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The definitions aren't being lost, they're being shadowed, as described in the [tutorial on contexts](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Contexts.html). *Mathematica* doesn't warn you about this because it only warns when there is shadowing between contexts that are listed in the `$ContextPath`. Since `Begin` only changes `$Context` and not `$ContextPath`, you don't get a warning when the symbol that causes shadowing is created.

Here's a pared-down example. (Quit the kernel before running each code block.)

If we define a symbol in a context and then switch to the context, we get the defined value:

```
sandbox`a = 1;
$Context = "sandbox`";
Context[a]
(* sandbox` *)
```

But if `a` has been created in the `` Global` `` context, `` Global`a `` is used, because [*Mathematica* looks at the contexts in `$ContextPath` before `$Context`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/43629/8253):

```
a;
sandbox`a = 1;
$Context = "sandbox`";
Context[a]
(* Global` *)
```

No shadowing warning is issued here, because `` sandbox` `` is not in the `$ContextPath`.

If we add `` sandbox` `` to `$ContextPath`, we get the shadowing warning, and `a` is found in whichever context comes first in the list:

```
PrependTo[$ContextPath, "sandbox`"];
a;
sandbox`a = 1;
Context[a]

(* During evaluation of In[1]:= a::shdw: Symbol a appears in multiple 
   contexts {sandbox`,Global`}; definitions in context sandbox` may shadow or 
   be shadowed by other definitions. >> *)
(* ==> sandbox` *)
```

The standard ways of dealing with shadowing are:

- If you are only interested in `` sandbox`a `` and inadvertently create `` Global`a ``, use `Remove` to remove `` Global`a ``:

  ```
  Begin["sandbox`"];
  a = 1;
  End[];

  a;
  Remove[a]

  Begin["sandbox`"];
  a
  End[];

  (* ==> 1 *)
  ```
- If you want to keep both `` Global`a `` and `` sandbox`a `` but refer by default to `` sandbox`a ``, use `BeginPackage` instead of `Begin`, which adds the context to `$ContextPath`:

  ```
  a = 2;

  BeginPackage["sandbox`"];
  a = 1;
  EndPackage[];

  a
  Global`a

  (* During evaluation of In[1]:= a::shdw: Symbol a appears in multiple contexts {sandbox`,Global`}; definitions in context sandbox` may shadow or be shadowed by other definitions. >> *)
  (* ==> 1 *)
  (* ==> 2 *)
  ```
- If you want to keep both `` Global`a `` and `` sandbox`a `` and refer by default to `` Global`a ``, use `Begin` as you have been doing.

For your purposes, however, you may want to manually manipulate `$ContextPath`, so you can enter and leave your sandbox. You can define

```
EnterSandbox[] := BeginPackage["sandbox`"];
sandbox`ExitSandbox[] := (
  EndPackage[]; 
  $ContextPath = DeleteCases[$ContextPath, "sandbox`"]
)
```

Then you can do:

```
EnterSandbox[];
a = 1;
ExitSandbox[];

a = 2;

EnterSandbox[];
a
ExitSandbox[];

a 

(* 1 *)
(* 2 *)
```

Comment: It really bothers me that the "current" context's own value for a symbol doesn't ALWAYS take precedence over other contexts. What the heck does it mean to "be in" a context, then?

Comment: @ibeatty It *used* to work that way but they changed it.  Reference [(43381)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/43381/121).  I do not know why it was changed.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, that reference is tremendously clarifying. Thanks!

Comment: @ibeatty In practice, this weirdness usually doesn't cause problems, because new contexts (at least new parent contexts) are usually created with `BeginPackage`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard A similar sort of mission creep happened with `$Path` between versions 6 and 9: [(59127)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/59127/path-hijacked-by-pacletmanager)

Comment: Hm, it looks like `BeginPackage` is not just for creating *Mathematica* packages to be imported by other code, despite its name.

Comment: @SimonRochester, in your definition of `sandbox'ExitSandbox[]`, I believe you mean `EndPackage[]` instead of `End[]`.

Comment: @ibeatty Yes, thanks. Actually, though, I think that as long as you're not nesting the context creation, `End` and `EndPackage` will both work the same after a `BeginPackage`.

Answer (score 10):

Indeed confusing, but can be explained.  [Please read here first on how Mathematica searches contexts for symbols.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/43629/12)

In short,

- `$Context` tells it where to *create* symbols.  It's for creation, not for lookup.
- `$ContextPath` tells it where to *look for* symbols but doesn't affect symbol creation.

  If the symbol is not found in any of the `$ContextPath` contexts, Mathematica proceeds to create it in `$Context`.  For this, it first needs to check if `$Context` already contains this name.  If it does, it won't need to create it after all.  Thus lookup will effectively fall back to `$Context` if (and only if) the symbol is not found in any `$ContextPath` contexts.

To add to the confusion, `Begin` only sets `$Context`, but not the `$ContextPath`.  Compare `BeginPackage` which also sets the `$ContextPath`.

Looking at your example:

```
Begin["sandbox`"];
a = 1;  (* sandbox`a is created here *)
ValueQ[a] (* there's no symbol named 'a' in any of the $ContextPath contexts so Mathematica falls back to looking in $Context *)
End[];

(* ==> True *)

ValueQ[a] (* Global`a is created here *)

(* ==> False *)

Begin["sandbox`"];
Names[Evaluate[Context[]] <> "*"]
ValueQ[a] (* this refers to Global`a since that symbol already exists and Global` is in $ContextPath *)
ValueQ[sandbox`a]
End[];

(* ==> {"sandbox`a"} *)
(* ==> False *)
(* ==> True *)
```

I hope this clears it up.

Comment: Somehow I never connected the idea that `$Context` is *only for creation* but now that makes sense.  Thanks!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard That's how I can make sense of it.  `$Context` is only for creation, but to be able to create the symbol, the system does need to check for existence first anyway.  Thus `$Context` effectively influences lookup too, out of necessity.  But this is a direct consequence of using it for creation, the primary function.  If we think this way, then suddenly it makes sense that `$Context` is searched only after `$ContextPath` ... but then there's that little thing that it wasn't always like this in the past ...

Comment: That turned on a light bulb here, +1

Comment: @Mr.Wizard & Szabolcs I have spent a whole evening once to understand this. It included rewritting on paper all context related symbols, marking their main purpose/influence.Reading tutorial wasn't much of help.  Still some things can only be deduced after tests because of inconsistencies in docs. After such evening I'm glad that I've learned something but I'm also pissed off on Wolfram because I feel like I wasted more time that I should've.

Comment: Sorry I had to share my feelings :-/ +1 ofc, we need more those "in short" answers to regular MMA usage questions. Not to mention that such fundamentals should be easy to find parts of docs.

Comment: Got it. I'm now quite curious why Wolfram decided to change this behavior; the old way seems much more like the way most programming languages work, and more convenient as well.

Comment: Okay, I'm going to go on the record here as saying that *Mathematica*'s handling of namespaces is completely and thoroughly idiotic. In production code, I am unable to `use BeginPackage` and `EndPackage`  to reliably or reproducibly control the context that a symbol is created in because of the fact that Mathematica parses my code before executing it, and creates symbols in contexts other than where they would be defined by the statements they appear in when those statements are actually evaluated. Shadowing occurs, and the results are (a) dumb and (b) variable depending on kernel history.

Comment: Followup: Programmatically clearing out a context with `Remove` after my package definitions have been evaluated, but before I've (supposedly) evaluated `foo=3` that context, can result in `Removed[foo]` rather than `3`. So the parsing scan hijacks my symbols and prevents me from using them as a literal reading of the code would suggest.

Comment: It seems "$Context is only for creation" is not a perfect explanation, because when i first Begin[] a context name MyContext` and define a funtion eg f[x], then before End[], i can use f[3] directly without MyContext`