# Why do we have to write context name when re-Begin[] a same context?

Tags: contexts

as the following picture shows, when I Begin[] a same context(same name), why i use the function yjn[](defined in the previous same name context) still have to write the context name?

[image]

similar question can be referenced(but still not solve my confusion)

[How symbol lookup actually works](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/43381/how-symbol-lookup-actually-works)

[Why does leaving and re-entering a context lose values defined in that context?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/88147/why-does-leaving-and-re-entering-a-context-lose-values-defined-in-that-context)

---

Ans:
Thanks for lericr's attention, the core is that i call yjn[] in Global` which will generate a Global`yjn[], so when i call yjn[] in MyContext` again, now there are two yjn[](how silly am I~). to confirm this thought, i comment the yjn[3] in the Global`, result is I can use short name yjn[] directly in MyContext`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All that `Begin` does is set the context, which basically just means it sets the automatic naming of new symbols. Every symbol has a fully qualified name that includes the full context. It's just a convenience that this fully qualified name is usually hidden from us.

Importantly, `Begin` doesn't change `$ContextPath`. So, when trying to resolve a symbol, it'll use whatever is discovered in `$ContextPath`.

At input 7, when you evaluated `yjn[3]`, you put a new symbol into the `Global'` context. Later you used `Begin` and evaluated `yjn[4]`. Well, `yjn` was found in `Global'`, and so that symbol's name is really `Global'yjn`. Since no definitions are associated to that symbol, you just get `yjn[4]` back.

To change `$ContextPath` you need to use `BeginPackage` and `EndPackage`.