# Inconsistent behaviour of availability of variables when re-entering `Context`

Tags: contexts

I am quite confused about `Context`. I have a long semi-manual signal processing task. I already did that for one signal and I need to do it for another one. I want to preserve all variables for both signals as their calculation is lengthy. So I thought of using `Context` for that (else, I would need to make new variables with new names and that would mean to change all the code.

Now, if I do the following sequnce of commands:

```
$Context
```

returns:

```
Out[1]= "Global`"
```

Starting a new context:

```
Begin["ContextA`"]
a = 3;
b = 33;
c = a + b;
{a, b, c}
End[]
```

returns:

```
"ContextA`"

{3, 33, 36}

"ContextA`"
```

Which context am I now in?

```
$Context
```

returns

```
Out[8]= "Global`"
```

Try:

```
a
```

returns:

```
Out[9]= a
```

Try

```
{ContextA`a, ContextA`b, ContextA`c}
```

returns

```
Out[11]= {3, 33, 36}
```

Up to now everything is as expected. But the problem starts when I want to go back to the context `ContextA`:

```
Begin["ContextA`"]
$Context
```

returns:

```
"ContextA`"

"ContextA`"
```

Correct but:

```
a
```

returns unexpectedly

```
Out[14]= a
```

Then

```
b
```

Makes more confusion by returning:

```
Out[15]= 33
```

the rest is as I was expecting:

```
c
```

returns

```
Out[16]= 36
```

So let's try again

```
a
```

returns

```
Out[17]= a
```

try something else

```
d = 123;
End[]
```

gives

```
Out[19]= "ContextA`"
```

Verify, i am out:

```
In[20]:= $Context

Out[20]= "Global`"
```

Where is `d`?

```
In[21]:= d

Out[21]= d

In[23]:= {ContextA`a, ContextA`b, ContextA`c, ContextA`d}

Out[23]= {3, 33, 36, 123}
```

Try again:

```
In[24]:= Begin["ContextA`"]
$Context

Out[24]= "ContextA`"

Out[25]= "ContextA`"

In[26]:= a

Out[26]= a

In[27]:= ContextA`a

Out[27]= 3
```

What is wrong with this? Why cannot I access `a` when I switch to the `ContextA`? What is the proper way to switching back to a given context to continue to work in that context so that I have access to all expressions that i previously created in that context?

At this point, I read the suggested posts [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/88147/why-does-leaving-and-re-entering-a-context-lose-values-defined-in-that-context) and [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/43381/how-symbol-lookup-actually-works) which seem to indicated that the way `a` behaves should be correct, but then, why the other variables are not behaving the same way?

Anyway, if I had to prepend `ContextA` to all variables after entering the context, then this is completely useless for my purpose as it is the same as having to rename all the variables. Is there a way to tell Mathematica, "Hey, now we are working with variables in `ContextA` so when I write `a`, you will interpret that as "ContextA`a"!"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is caused by your 8th input, namely:

```
a
Out[8] = a
```

If you remove this line, you'll find that `a` behaves as expected.

But why is that? The reason has to do with [`$ContextPath`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/%24ContextPath.html), and how it interacts with [`$Context`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/%24Context.html). In essence, the problem boils down to how symbols are created/found:

1. If the symbol is of the form `` someContext`symbol ``, the symbol is always taken from/created in `` someContext` ``
2. If the symbol is of the form  `` `symbol ``, the symbol is always taken from/created in the current `$Context`. (symbols of the form  `` `subContext`symbol `` are taken to refer to a symbol in the subcontext `` context`subContext` ``  of the current `$Context`)
3. Otherwise, the symbol is looked for in the contexts in `$ContextPath` in order. If it is found in any of them, it is taken from there. If it is not, the symbol is taken from/created in the current `$Context`. This priority is mentioned in the last sentence [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ModularityAndTheNamingOfThings.html#28286) (emphasis mine):

> Conflicts can occur not only between symbols in different packages, but also between symbols in packages and symbols that you introduce directly in your Wolfram Language session. If you define a symbol in your current context, then this symbol may become shadowed by another symbol with the same short name in packages that you read in. **The reason for this is that the Wolfram Language searches for symbols in contexts on the context search path before looking in the current context.**

We can now take a look at a simplified example (make sure to enter each line in a separate cell):

```
Begin["ContextA`"]
(* Out[1]= "ContextA`" *)

$ContextPath
(* Out[2]= {"System`", "Global`"} *)

a = 5
(* Out[3]= 5 *)

Context@a
(* Out[4]= "ContextA`" *)

End[]
(* Out[5]= "ContextA`" *)

ContextA`a
(* Out[6]= 5 *)

a
(* Out[7]= a *)

Begin["ContextA`"]
(* Out[8]= "ContextA`" *)

Context@a
(* Out[9]= "Global`" *)

Context@ContextA`a
(* Out[10]= "ContextA`" *)

Context@`a
(* Out[11]= "ContextA`" *)
```

The problem now starts with input 7: We access `a`, which causes `a` to be created in the current context `` Global` `` . If we now switch back to `` ContextA` `` , this symbol is still in a context in `$ContextPath`, which will always be found before the symbols in the current context.

To work around this, you can:

- use symbols of the form  `` `symbol `` (as shown in line 11 above)
- modify `$ContextPath` to include your current context (remember to reset it again if you want)
- use [`BeginPackage`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BeginPackage.html)/[`EndPackage`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EndPackage.html)
  instead which come with automatic `$ContextPath` management. Note however that they will
  also leave the created context on `$ContextPath` afterwards, and clear out `$ContextPath` while you're between `BeginPackage[]` and `EndPackage[]`.

Comment: Oh there was the dog hiding, the fact that I accessed `a` in the context that was in the `ContextPath` but the others I did not. Now a followup, not sure how to ask: Why does typing `a` and executing "create" `a`. What does that even mean in this sense to "create". I understand (though superficially)  things like `a=1` or `a:=b` etc there is assignment but `a` does not assign anything, so why suddenly it "pops up" into the memory world?

Comment: @atapaka Whenever you enter any expression into the front-end and evaluate it, the box version (can be seen via Cell > Show Expression) is sent to the kernel, which uses `MakeExpression` to turn this into a symbolic expression to be evaluated (strictly speaking, this is the place where symbols are created, effectively using something like `Symbol`). This allows the kernel to uniformly handle any input: It will always be a combination of numbers, strings & symbols, each symbol having a name and a context. [cont.]

Comment: [cont.] This means that even the simplest case of evaluating `a` needs to create the symbol `a`. Maybe it also helps to think about a slightly less extreme example like `list = {a,b}` - even without any assignment, both `a` and `b` need to exist as symbols. Otherwise, what would `list` contain? Or take `Context[a]` or `SymbolName[a]`, where clearly, `a` needs to be a symbol.

Comment: So, put differently: Simply "mentioning" a symbol in any way will create it (in the current/specified context). As mentioned, this happens during the `MakeExpression` step (for notebooks)/the parsing step (for package files). Only then is the code evaluated and any assignments etc. are performed (you'll note that this is a completely separate step from symbol creation).

Answer (score 3):

Walking through step by step:

```
$ContextPath (* this is the path that Mathematica searches when looking for the definition of a symbol*)
```

`` {"System`", "Global`"} `` <- this means that it will first look in System and then in Global.

```
$Context (* this is the context in which new symbols will be put*)
```

`` Global` ``  <- any new symbol will be in the Global context

```
Begin["ContextA`"] (* this changes $Context, but NOT $ContextPath*)
```

`` ContextA` ``

```
$Context
```

`` ContextA` ``

```
$ContextPath
```

`` {"System`", "Global`"} ``

```
a = 3;
Context[a]
```

`` ContextA` ``  <- expected

```
End[]
```

`` ContextA` ``  <- this tells us which context we just left

```
$Context
```

`` Global` ``  <- new symbols will be in this context

```
$ContextPath
```

`` {"System`", "Global`"} `` <- still the same, this has never changed

```
a; (* MMA will start looking in its context path for this symbol*)
Context[a]
```

`` Global` ``

At this point, Mathematica started looking for the symbol `a` in its context path, but it didn't find it. Therefore, it will create a new symbol in the current context, which is Global. However, the `a` in ContextA is still remembered:

```
ContextA`a
```

`3`

Okay, so, the question is how do we add ContextA to the context path? That's what BeginPackage (and the associated EndPackage) are for. See the docs for $ContextPath.

Comment: Guess I was a bit slow.

Comment: I'm a bit amazed how we all managed to answer within a minute of each other, all  with quite lengthy texts :)

Comment: I think they were all submitted within 30 seconds

Comment: @JasonB. Now the same thing is happening with the comments...