# Get[..., Path-> {...}] does not shield against paclets directories

Tags: packages, files-and-directories, compatibility, paclets

Let's create a test package/paclet in a standard `$UserBaseDirectory/Applications`:

```
root = FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Applications", "TestPaclet", ##}]&;

CreateFile @ root["Kernel", "init.m"]
Export[ root["Kernel", "init.m"], "Echo[$InputFileName]", "Text"];

Export[
    root["PacletInfo.m"]
  , Paclet[Name -> "TestPaclet",Version -> "0.0.1", MathematicaVersion -> "11+",
    Description -> "", Creator -> "Kuba", 
    Extensions -> { {"Kernel", Context -> "TestPaclet`"}}]  
];
```

And let's try it:

```
Get["TestPaclet`"];

Get["TestPaclet`", Path -> {$HomeDirectory}]
```

> >> ...\Applications\TestPaclet\Kernel\init.m

> Get::noopen: Cannot open TestPaclet`.
>
> ```
> $Failed
> ```

Before `Paclets` appeared, `Path` option for `Get` shielded against the default `$Path`. Which I find expected and desired but I can agree it is subjective. Anyway, it is not the case for default paclets repositories:

```
PacletInstall @ PackPaclet @ root[]

Get["TestPaclet`"];

Get["TestPaclet`", Path -> {$HomeDirectory}];
```

> ```
> Paclet[TestPaclet,0.0.1,<>]
> ```
>
> >> ...\Paclets\Repository\TestPaclet-0.0.1\Kernel\init.m
>
> >> ...\Paclets\Repository\TestPaclet-0.0.1\Kernel\init.m

Considering previous behavior I find the new one a bug.

> [CASE:4016445] was created

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$Path hijacked by PacletManager?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/59127/path-hijacked-by-pacletmanager)

Comment: @ilian very closely related but it does not cover Paclets/Repository scenario and Path option. And the real question I have is how to block my Get from paclets directory? If there is no way then there is a serious problem.

Comment: @ilian ref/Get: "Get[name,Path->{"dir1","dir2", ...}] successively searches for files in each of the diri." so my example exposes at least a documentation bug because the last code line of mine clearly does more.

Comment: But the previous question also covers overriding `$Path` and your `Paclets/Repository` is just where the paclet is, nothing more.

Comment: @ilian I'm abusing the fact the `Path` (the option) does not say anything about `$Path`. And again, I don't insist on ``Get["TestPaclet`", 
 Path -> {FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Applications"}]}]`` reaching `Applications` (though that is expected). Where is that (this or linked) behavior documented? If we mark it a duplicate the OP deserves bugs tag.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not going to write an answer, but in terms of getting your desired behavior, try

```
Block[{Internal`PacletFindFile}, 
 Get["TestPaclet`", Path -> {$HomeDirectory}]]
```

> Get::noopen: Cannot open TestPaclet`.

```
(* $Failed *)
```

Comment: Thanks. And re this and `FindFile` case. It is nowhere documented. Is there any reason not to give it [tag:bugs] +/- [tag:documentation]?

Comment: It’s certainly undocumented, like a great many things about the paclet manager (there is a good Q & A about some of them too).